# $.each con JSON capturar diferentes variables

Tags: javascript, laravel, html5, div

Desde un ajax, consulto un controlador que me devuelve un array de imágenes codificadas.

Si envío una cantidad de imágenes fijas, en el array, puedo capturarlas y mostrarlas de manera correcta.
Hasta ahí funciona bien. Pero me pidieron que no se sabe la cantidad de imágenes que podrían venir, entonces no sé cómo iterarlas en la parte de la vista.

FUNCIONA OK DE ESTA MANERA:

controlador de LARAVEL:

```
public function damefotos(Request $request){
//todo el proceso de recoleccion de fotos  de la bd
$imagen1 =//la foto
$imagen2 = //lafoto
$imagen3 = //lafoto

$imagenes[] = array('imagen1' => $imagen1, 'imagen2' => $imagen2, 'imagen3' => $imagen3);

  return json_encode($imagenes);

}
```

en la vista en js mediante ajax.

```
.done(function (data) {
                    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
                        if (item.imagen1 != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {
                            $("#foto1").attr("src", item.imagen1);
                        }
                        if (item.imagen2 != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {
                            $("#foto2").attr("src", item.imagen2);
                        }

                        if (item.imagen3 != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {
                            $("#foto3").attr("src", item.imagen3);
                        }
                    });
                })
```

De esta manera, funciona bien, y me muestra las 3 imágenes, bien, sin problema.
Ahora intento iterar para cantidades de imágenes que no se conoce, y es donde tengo el problema.

En la parte del controlador he logrado enviar todas las fotos en un array así:
CONTROLADOR:

```
public function damefotos(Request $request){
    //todo el proceso de recoleccion de fotos  de la bd

$new_array = // las cantidad de fotos
  $contador = 1;
    foreach($new_array as $fot1)
        {
            $contenido= // proceso para capturar la imagen;
            $imagen1 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $contenido;
            $imagenes[] = array('imagen'.$contador => $imagen1);
            $contador +=1;
        }
        
    return json_encode($imagenes);
}
```

En ese punto todo funciona, no hay problema y me devuelve un array con las N fotos.

El resultado es algo como:

```
[{"imagen1":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJR..../9k="},
{"imagen2":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA...7Awr\/9k="},
{"imagen3":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....7Awr\/9k="},
{"imagen4":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....r\/9k="}]
```

En el .DONE del ajax, en la parte de mi vista, he intentado varias cosas, pero he logrado hasta este punto, que es donde no sé cómo iterar y que me muestre las N fotos que pueden venir.

```
.done(function (data) {
                    var contador=1;
                    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
                        var nombre = 'item.imagen'+contador;

                        if (nombre != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {

                            $("#foto1").attr("src", item.imagen1);

                        }
                        contador +=1;
                    });

                })
```

En este punto me muestra una sola imagen, claramente estoy llamando a un solo div ("#foto1"). Pero necesito crear los divs de manera dinámica y recorrer las imágenes.
¿Qué podría hacer gracias?

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes ID de imagen en el arreglo, que va desde *imagen1* hasta *imagenX*:

```
[
    {"imagen1":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJR..../9k="},
    {"imagen2":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA...7Awr\/9k="},
    {"imagen3":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....7Awr\/9k="},
    ...
    {"imagenX":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....r\/9k="}
]
```

Solo necesitas armar correctamente el nombre de la propiedad y usarla (dentro de corchetes) para comparar o asignar:

```
let contador = 1;
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
    // Crear nombre de propiedad
    let nombre = 'imagen' + contador;

    // Verificar que la imagen no sea solo la descripción BASE64
    if (item[nombre] != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {
        // Usa el nombre para especificar ID del elemento HTML a actualizar
        $('#' + nombre).attr("src", item.[nombre]);
    }
    contador ++; // Esto es igual a contador += 1
});
```

Creo que una forma más fácil de lograrlo sería tener dos propiedades en cada objeto, uno para ID y otro para imagen:

```
public function damefotos(Request $request){
    //todo el proceso de recoleccion de fotos  de la bd
    $new_array = // las cantidad de fotos
    $contador = 1;
    foreach($new_array as $fot1) {
        $contenido= // proceso para capturar la imagen;
        $imagen1 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $contenido;
        $imagenes[] = [
            // Incluye # para identificar el elemento HTML
            'nombre' => '#imagen' + $contador;
            'imagen' => $imagen1
        ];
        $contador ++;
    }
    return json_encode($imagenes);
}
```

El objeto resultante sería algo como:

```
[
    {"nombre": "#imagen1", "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJR..../9k="},
    {"nombre": "#imagen2", "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA...7Awr\/9k="},
    {"nombre": "#imagen3", "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....7Awr\/9k="},
    ...
    {"nombre": "#imagenX", "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....r\/9k="}
]
```

Luego, en Javascript, ya no necesitas el contador, solo acceder a las propiedades *nombre* e *imagen*:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
    // Verificar que la imagen no sea solo la descripción BASE64
    if (item.imagen != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {
        // item.nombre ya tiene ID del elemento HTML
        $(item.nombre).attr("src", item.imagen);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios fallos en tu código y muchos de ellos se deben a que no has optado por un camino fácil para estructurar tu JSON. Generalmente, cuando creas arrays de objetos es mejor dar a cada objeto dentro del array el mismo nombre de clave (en este caso `imagen`), así ya sabrás que la clave se llama así y podrás sacar la información sin tener que recurrir a triquiñuelas para crear las cosas a mano.

Otra cosa es que no necesitas un contador aparte para saber los índices. Puedes usar `i` (en este caso le sumamos `i` porque los índices de arrays empiezan en `0`  y tus elementos empiezan por `1`).

También, en el `if` tú estabas buscando si el valor entero **no era igual a `data:image/jpeg;base64,`**. Hay varias confusiones en ese punto. En primer lugar siempre entraría en ese `if` porque `data:image/jpeg;base64,` nunca será igual al valor del json, pues ese contenido es parte de la cadena. Si la intención ahí es verificar si la imagen es o no de ese tipo, lo propio sería usar `contains`, para verificar que el dato contiene la cadena `data:image/jpeg;base64,`. Dado que todas lo contienen, he puesto el `if` en positivo, para que veas la cuestión de la imagen funcionando... Lo puedes cambiar si es de otro modo. La verdad es que ese `if` no es para nada claro.

De todos modos si no lo puedes modificar, con el siguente código debería funcionar.

```js
let data = `[{
    "imagen1": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJR..../9k="
  },
  {
    "imagen2": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA...7Awr\/9k="
  },
  {
    "imagen3": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....7Awr\/9k="
  },
  {
    "imagen4": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....r\/9k="
  }
]`;

$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, item) {
  /*Hay que construir referencia a la llave*/
  var mKey = 'imagen' + (i+1);
  /*Referencia al id del elemento img*/
  var mId= '#foto' + (i+1);
  /*Contenido destinado al src*/
  var mSrc=item[mKey];
  /*
    Se comprueba si contiene data:image...
    Lo he puesto en positivo para que veas el resultado, porque todos coinciden
  */
  if (mSrc.includes('data:image/jpeg;base64')) {
    $(mId).attr("src", mSrc);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="foto1" />

<img id="foto2" />

<img id="foto3" />

<img id="foto4" />
```

---

### Facilitar estructura del JSON

Como decía al principio, tú puedes llamar `imagen` a todas las claves (puesto que estás en un array y un objeto no se choca con otro). Así, no estás obligado a hacer trucos para obtener `imagen1, imagen2, imagenN` Esto se agradece, sobre todo en estructuras más complejas.

```js
let data = `[{
    "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJR..../9k="
  },
  {
    "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA...7Awr\/9k="
  },
  {
    "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....7Awr\/9k="
  },
  {
    "imagen": "data:image\/jpeg;base64,\/9j\/4AA....r\/9k="
  }
]`;

$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, item) {
  /*Referencia al id del elemento img*/
  var mId= '#foto' + (i+1);
  /*Contenido destinado al src*/
  var mSrc=item.imagen;
  /*
    Se comprueba si contiene data:image...
    Lo he puesto en positivo para que veas el resultado, porque todos coinciden
  */
  if (mSrc.includes('data:image/jpeg;base64')) {
    $(mId).attr("src", mSrc);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="foto1" />

<img id="foto2" />

<img id="foto3" />

<img id="foto4" />
```